# Why does not DocumentFragment has getElementsByName?

Tags: javascript, documentfragment, html-templates

I am following [the instructions given on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) to use `<template>`. Slightly different those give in example, my code is:

```html
<template id="template">
    <tr>
        <td name="id"></td>
        <td name="name"></td>
        <td name="size"></td>
        <td name="Status">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

```js
// ...
const item = document.importNode(template.content, true);
item.getElementsByName("id")[0].textContent = token;
item.getElementsByName("name")[0].textContent = file.name;
item.getElementsByName("size")[0].textContent = file.size;
fileList.appendChild(item);
// ...
```

However, it appears that `item`, of which the `__proto__` is `DocumentFragment` has no `getElementsByName` method.
Is it very confusing for me now that there is `getElementById` and `querySelector`.

Is there any reason why?

In case related, my browsers are FireFox Quantum 69.0.1 are Chrome Canary 79.0.3918.0.

Comment: `DocumentFragment` is intended to be very lightweight, it doesn't implement the full `Document` interface. It doesn't have any of the `getElementsByXXX` methods, just `getElementById`.

Comment: Note also that regular HTML elements don't implement `getElementsByName`, either. It's only available on the `document` element.

Comment: I think `querySelector(All)` would be heavier? Am I misunderstanding "lightweight"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out "regular HTML elements don't implement getElementsByName". I did not know it at all. But regardless of your former comment concerning lightweight, regular HTML elements have `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` which are not owned by `DocumentFragment`. I will edit my question...

Comment: Emmm. It seems that the question is not good. I think it would be better to close it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DocumentFragment` doesn't implement any of the `getElementsBy*` methods. However, it does implement `querySelector()`, so you can use

```
item.querySelector("[name=name]").textContent = token;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did notice that there is `querySelector`. But I am just wondering: now that there is `querySelector(All)` and `getElementById` method implemented on `DocumentFragment`, why isn't there `getElementsBy*` also? Is there any specific considerations to prevent the standard/implementation or am I missing something (as a newbie in DOM/JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0):

Document object is used to access and edit any HTML element getElementbyId(), getElementbyTagName() and getElementsByClassName() are method used by document object.

as you are trying to access Nodes of Template element using method of document object it will not work. you can implement the same code to append in your filelist object.

```js
var Node1 = document.getElementById("template");
var Node2 = document.importNode(Node1, true);
document.getElementById("Table1").appendChild(Node2);
```

```html
<template id="template">
    <tr>
       <td name="id"></td>
        <td name="name"></td>
        <td name="size"></td>
        <td name="Status">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>

<Table id="Table1">
    <tr>
        <td name="id"> 1</td>
        <td name="name"> A </td>
        <td name="size"> 20 </td>
        <td name="Status"> N
        </td>
    </tr>
</Table>
```

Comment: There is getElementsByName(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Comment: Thanks. In HTML5, the "name" attribute is deprecated and has been replaced by the "id" attribute for many elements. Use the document.getElementById() method where it is appropriate. Also look at the getElementsByClassName() and getElementsByTagName() methods.

Comment: `id` doesn't replace `name` for form inputs.